# C Library Find Difference Between Two Arrays

Tags: c, function

Given 2 arrays I need a C Function/Library that will find what's different between 2 arrays.

```
array1[] ={"a","b","c","e"}
array2[] ={"a","c","e"}
```

and the function should return

```
{"b"}
```

These 2 arrays are **guaranteed** to be sorted, but not the same size. I just need this function to be fast.

Comment: "b" is unique because it doesn't exist in both arrays, I haven't tried anything yet, It would be simply to loop over both arrays multiple times but I need it to be faster than that.

Comment: @Icestorm: OK, apologies, perhaps in some way you could call `b` "unique", though it's unclear what happens if you have arrays `{a,a,a,b,b}` and `{c,c,d,d}`. It's best to avoid such needlessly ambiguous terms. I think you're looking for either "set difference" or "symmetric difference".

Comment: Why should it be fast? Why should it use library functions?

Comment: Write your function and we will try to improve it. Try to solve the problem in linear time.

Comment: @wildplasser: In the actual post I said Function or Library. I figured there may be a C Library that implemented such functionality. I only gave an example of what I needed, It needs to be fast because I plan to use this on large arrays and an algorithm that O(N^3) or something would be too slow

Comment: The solution is obviously a "merge" kind of thing, like Oli's reply below (which is min(N,M) IMHO). Removing the duplicates is left as an exercise to the writer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an O(n) algorithm:

Create two pointers, each initialized to point at the first element of each array.  Every time *p1 < *p2, add *p1 to the output array and increment p1.  Same for p2.  If they are equal, increment both.

I'll leave you to figure out how to handle duplicate elements, and what to do when one pointer reaches the end of its array.

[Also, if you're able to use C++, then you should just use [std::set_symmetric_difference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference/).]

Comment: That's missing a description of what happens when `*p1 == *p2`, non?

Answer (score 0):

@Oli Charlesworth

if arr1[]={"a","b","c"}
and arr2[]={"d","e","f"}

in this case i guess ur logic will traverse elements of array(whichever is lower) but there is no need as by first comparsion only u can find the result hence result is possible for this case in o(1).....